# Android SDK Stopwatch App: How to Simultaneously Reset and Pause Stopwatch

Tags: java, android-studio

Essentially, I have a Stopwatch app that currently has the functionality to start a timer, stop said timer, and record the data that is read at the time of pressing the record button while pausing the current timer value.

Ex:

- Presses Start Button
- Runs Stopwatch for 0:00:11 and Presses Record
- Timer is stopped, data is recorded to array, and timer is paused at
  0:00:11
- After pressing start again, the timer is reset and a new
  trial begins

Issue: Whenever the timer is stopped, it pauses on the elapsed time rather than resetting back to zero and staying paused there

I've attempted to incorporate the code from the start button to reset the timer value back to zero immediately after recording the data; however, this results in the immediate start of the next trial after pressing the Record button.

```java
long startTime=0L,timeinMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=0L,updateTime=0L;

 Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeinMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updateTime = timeSwapBuff + timeinMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updateTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs %= 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updateTime % 1000);
            txtTimer.setText("" + mins +":"+ String.format("%2d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%3d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);

            }
        });


 btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view){
            TextView txtValue = (TextView) time.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);   
            txtValue.setText(txtTimer.getText());
            String timerString = txtTimer.getText().toString();
            stringNums.add(timerString); //adds string timer value to an array


            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread); //pauses timer


          //startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();      
          //customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);  
          //Restarts timer to zero but immediately begins next trial
}
```

- Expected result: Click Record button, data is recorded, reset, and paused
- Actual result: Click Record button, data is recorded, paused, and not reset to zero until next press of Start button.

Comment: please check this https://www.android-examples.com/android-create-stopwatch-example-tutorial-in-android-studio/. thank u

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by utilizing "textView.setText("00:00:00");" from the reset method after my pausing code, so thank you. If you post the answer separately I can accept it

Comment: Oh, any way finally you did it, that's great. thank you